# POJO for nested json

Tags: android, json, gson

i am new on JSON and have a problem on creating POJO for followed JSON input.

```
    [
    {
"score":1,
"popularity":3,
"name":"Brad Pitt",
"id":287,
"biography":"test",
"url":"http://www.themoviedb.org/person/287",
"profile":[
    {
        "image":{
            "type":"profile",
            "size":"thumb",
            "height":68,
            "width":45,
            "url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w45/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg",
            "id":"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"
        }
    },
    {
        "image":{
            "type":"profile",
            "size":"profile",
            "height":281,
            "width":185,
            "url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg",
            "id":"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"
        }
    },
    {
        "image":{
            "type":"profile",
            "size":"h632",
            "height":632,
            "width":416,
            "url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/h632/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg",
            "id":"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"
        }
    },
    {
        "image":{
            "type":"profile",
            "size":"original",
            "height":1969,
            "width":1295,
            "url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg",
            "id":"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f"
        }
    }
],
"version":685,
"last_modified_at":"2013-02-16 07:11:15 UTC"
  }
  ]
```

i have created three POJO's for this one of them is main person class and this one contains profile object also. Profile object returns image list.:

```
    public class Person implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6794898677027141412L;

  public String biography;
  public String id;
  public String last_modified_at;
  public String name;
  public String popularity;
  public String score;
  public String url;
  public String version;
  public ArrayList<Profile> profile;

  //getters and setters
    }

    public class Profile implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6482559829789740926L;

  public ArrayList<Image> image;

    }


    public class Image implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2428562977284114465L;

    public String type;
    public String url;
    public String size;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    }
```

to retrieve data i am using gson:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType();
  List<Person> details = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

when i run this i got:

```
  02-17 11:04:50.531: E/AndroidRuntime(405): Caused by:  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3
```

updated Image POJO:

```
public class Image implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2428562977284114465L;
private Object image;

public class ImageInner {

    public static final String SIZE_ORIGINAL = "original";
    public static final String SIZE_MID = "mid";
    public static final String SIZE_COVER = "cover";
    public static final String SIZE_THUMB = "thumb";
    public static final String TYPE_PROFILE = "profile";
    public static final String TYPE_POSTER = "poster";
    public String type;
    public String url;
    public String size;
    public int width;
    public int height;

}
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually *really* close, with two errors:

1) The error you're receiving is telling you that at the very beginning of the JSON it was expecting the start of an array (`[`) , but got the start of an object (`{`) instead. The JSON you have posted is *not* what you're feeding Gson (see below).

2) When you correct the above, you have one small problem in your `Person` POJO:

```
public ArrayList<Profile> profile;
```

should be:

```
public ArrayList<Image> profile;
```

You actually don't need your `Profile` class; `profile` in the JSON *is* an array. As-is you would receive another error similar to what you're receiving now because it would be expecting an ArrayList of `Profile` objects: `"profile":[{"image":[{imageobject},...]},{"image":[{imageobject},...]}]`

If you fix number two and feed Gson the JSON you have posted, it works perfectly. You've posted an array of `Person` objects but what you actually have in your code (in `json`) is either just one object ... or an object that contains the array you have posted. The small example below works perfectly (after correcting your `Person` class):

```
public class App
{
        static String json = "[{\"score\":1,\"popularity\":3,\"name\":\"Brad Pitt\",\"id\":287," +
        "\"biography\":\"test\",\"url\":\"http://www.themoviedb.org/person/287\",\"profile\":" +
        "[{\"image\":{\"type\":\"profile\",\"size\":\"thumb\",\"height\":68,\"width\":45,\"url\":" +
        "\"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w45/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg\"," +
        "\"id\":\"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f\"}},{\"image\":{\"type\":\"profile\",\"size\":\"profile\"," +
        "\"height\":281,\"width\":185,\"url\":\"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg\"," +
        "\"id\":\"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f\"}},{\"image\":{\"type\":\"profile\",\"size\":\"h632\",\"height\":632,\"width\":416,"+
        "\"url\":\"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/h632/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg\"," +
        "\"id\":\"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f\"}},{\"image\":{\"type\":\"profile\",\"size\":\"original\",\"height\":1969," +
        "\"width\":1295,\"url\":\"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/w8zJQuN7tzlm6FY9mfGKihxp3Cb.jpg\"," +
        "\"id\":\"4ea5cb8c2c0588394800006f\"}}],\"version\":685,\"last_modified_at\":\"2013-02-16 07:11:15 UTC\"" +
        "}]";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType();
        List<Person> details = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
    }
}
```

**Edit to add:** You actually have some type conversions going on that Gson is handling for you ... but you may not really want. For example in your JSON `score` is an `int` but in your POJO you've made it a `String`. Gson silently does the conversion.

Also, simply creating a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) like what I did above can help you debug these issues.

Comment: Hi brian, i will check the received json and update the Person POJO as you stated. I will give information when i try. thank you

Comment: hi brian, i think i missed one point in this answer because even if the image attributes are populated when i get list of person observed that all of image attributes are null. do you have any idea on that?

Comment: ok i have solved it. updated Image class in question. thank you again